# Remove an object n times from array list in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, integer, conditional-statements

Alright, I'm making a method that should be able to remove objects from an array list through the use of a string input.

Say I want to remove the following numbers: {1,2,4,3,3,1} from an arraylist. How can I ensure that it only removes 1 & 3 twice and 4 & 2 once?

What I have is:

```
mv.displayMessages("choosedicestokeep");
String in = mv.getInput();

for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
    int x = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = rollingHand.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ){
    int i = it.next();
        if (x == i) {
        finalHand[finalArrIndex] = i;
        it.remove();
        finalArrIndex++;
    }
}
}
```

But this checks the arraylist "RollingHand" and removes ALL instances of a number and not the number of times I write a number which is what I want.

So if i enter {1,1,1,2,2,4} it should remove three 1s, two 2s and one 4.

Comment: you can use break to exit the for loop

Comment: what are you trying to return?

Comment: Ah, of course! Why didn't I see it for what it was. I was staring too deep into it and was considering counters and booleans. Thank you man!

Comment: Is rollingHand a list? you can call rollingHand.remove(Integer.create(x))

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4584292/mike Solved the obvious answer.

Breaking to a statement outside the inner loop solved the problem.

The method doesn't return anything because it sets a private int[] finalHand in the class which is later accessed by other methods.

All cred to Mike!